# Are there spacetimes with zones that can reverse the relationship between proper time and coordinate time?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics

On a surface embedded in Euclidian space, where the metric signature is all positive, it is possible for a particle traveling along a geodesic to encounter a curved bit and then get turned around so that it heads in the opposite direction (so that an increase in the parameter of the curve leads to a change in the coordinate in the opposite direction as before).

Could there be a manifold that did the same turning-around trick, but in a timelike direction? Would this create particles for which increasing proper time corresponded to decreasing coordinate time?

### How this idea is distinct from closed timelike curves

Oddly, last time I asked this question, it was closed as a duplicate of this other question:
[What would a closed timelike curve look like?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191538/what-would-a-closed-timelike-curve-look-like) This is unfortunate because it had a very good answer from yukterez that I was planning to accept! So here is an explanation of how I am not asking about closed timelike curves:

#### 1. A patch of spacetime that turns worldlines around would not always create closed curves.

A closed timelike curve must be, well, closed. If an object were to enter in to a part of spacetime like I am describing, it could exit at a different point in space and head backwards through time (with respect to its proper time) in such a way that it did not return to its starting point. Therefore the set of things I am talking about is not a subset of all closed timelike curves.

#### 2. Closed timelike curves do not always involve coordinate time moving opposite to proper time.

A simple example of a geometry leading to closed timelike curves would be the torus. An object heading in to the future would always show up back in the past. However, for any natural time coordinates this would *not* reverse the direction of proper time with respect to coordinate time. At any point along the worldline of the object, advancing proper time would correspond to advancing coordinate time. This would not be the case for what I am talking about! Therefore, the set of closed timelike curves is not a subset of what I am talking about.

#### Conclusion

Since CTCs are neither a superset nor a subset of what I am talking about, I think we must all agree that this is not a question about closed timelike curves per se.

### Illustration

Here is a depiction of a geodesic like what I'm imaging. Please forgive any inaccuracies, I am not a good artist! (I meant to draw the ribbon twisting so that it would actually be a geodesic in Euclidian space but it didn't come out right.) This is mainly intended to be interpreted strictly by a definition: proper time and coordinate time align for a while, then the geodesic turns around and they go opposite.
[image]

Comment: Do your candidate geodesics have to remain causally connected with the rest of the universe ? Or will you accept a geodesic that crosses the event horizon of a black hole, for example ?

Comment: @gandalf61 If they remained causally connected that would be cooler, but no, they don't have to be. However for the sake of avoiding trivial solutions I will impose an additional constraint: it would be best if you could not get rid of the "proper time goes reverse to coordinate time" thing by changing coordinate systems. My illustration satisfies this because you could put the forward and backward parts of the worldline on the same chart - so one of the  segments has to move opposite to coordinate time (whichever direction you choose for coordinate time.)

Comment: @gandalf61 I can't think of any way to get a reversal out of a mere coordinate artifact and it may not be possible, but if it *is* possible, I think that is really the only thing I would not consider a well-spirited solution.

Comment: If you cross the Cauchy horizon of a rotating black hole with the right angle the proper time arrow can get reversed and the black hole becomes a white hole in your frame of reference, but before the arrow of time changes direction it runs to infinity, and then back. In that finite proper time moment where coordinate time goes to infinity all the infinitely blueshifted radiation that falls into your path will grill you, but if you somehow survive that infinite blueshift, afterwards your time arrow would be reversed and you could leave the time reversed black hole, which is just a white hole.

Comment: That situation is different from the Schwarzschild case where the sign change of gtt/grr and the infinite blueshift at the horizon is just a coordinate artefact of stationary observers, which can't exist at and behind the horizon, so in that case no one's proper time really changes. In the rotating case on the other hand you can indeed arrange for two observers to meet each other with opposing proper time arrows so they could listen to each other talking backwards (but only if they survive the infinite blueshift that hits them at the moment of their time reversal).